# What are some good references on conductometry as an analytical technique?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, reference-request, conductivity

Non of the standard undergraduate textbooks in analytical chemistry (such as Skoog, Harris) discusses conductometry as an analytical technique. I wonder whether this technique is obsolete. Or is it taught under some other area such as physical chemistry ?

Can someone please point me to some good references on this matter ? I am particularly interested in text books.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certainly no expert in the field (in fact, I know nothing about it) but I imagine this 225+ page text will prove to be useful for you:
[Oscillometry and Conductometry: International Series of Monographs in Analytical Chemistry, Volume 21](https://books.google.com/books?id=o8X9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PR13&dq=conductometry&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIyp63rJzvxgIVRyqICh3jhwkZ#v=onepage&q=conductometry&f=false) by E. Pungor is available via Google Books. You might be able to find a used copy of this book somewhere (it was published in 1965).